# Why is Google using this anti-pattern sign in feature?

Tags: usability, interaction-design, user-behavior, google, anti-patterns

Google has a feature "Sign in with Google" that auto appears on any site that supports it.

[image]

This seems to have harmful UX repocussions?

1. If Apple, Facebook, and others follow the same pattern we'll end up with this or worse

   [image]
2. It shows up a few moments after the page loads appearing directly under the fingers where you're likely scrolling if on mobile meaning you're likely to click it by accident.

   [image]

   Note in the gif above I deliberately kept my finger high so I didn't accidently click it since I knew it would soon appear. If you click it by accident your email address is immediately shared with the site even though you never intended to click it in the first place. Cancelling your account will not help as your email address will already be in their database (and likely already added to marketing emails)

Why would Google use this arguably poor UX design?

Comment: Only the relevant designers can really give you the reasons for this design. They might not be Google's designers by the way, but Medium's choice of implementing Google sign-in.

Comment: This partilcular UX is provided by Google in an iframe, not by the website itself. I can't be any other way otherwise the site could read the email address even though it hasn't been authroized yet. So the UX is designed by Google.

Comment: I was just reading an article a few weeks ago that there are a lot of sites playing tricks with this. Even on private browsing, users don't even need to accept or anything, emails are being read by the site somehow and users get a mail from the site or its sponsors right afterwards. Quite worrying

Comment: "_Why would Google use this arguably poor UX design?_" <cynic>Because it potentially makes them more money?</cynic>